# SetTimeout call function with parameter "this" inside addEventListener

Tags: javascript, settimeout, addeventlistener

Here is my code.

```
document.getElementById("t-option").addEventListener("click", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        myFunction(this);
    }, 1500)
});
```

I want "this" to return the "t-option". It is a radio button and I want to know each time which one has been called.

Maybe there is a complete alternative way to do this, I don't know.

Comment: `document.getElementById("t-option").addEventListener("click", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        myFunction(this);
    }.bind(this), 1500)
});` or `document.getElementById("t-option").addEventListener("click", function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        myFunction(this);
    }, 1500)
});`would also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you.

```js
function myFunction(self)
{
    console.log(self);
}

var option = document.getElementById("t-option");
option.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() { myFunction(self);}, 1500);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="t-option">
```

Comment: this was more than awesome. It worked exactly as I wanted.
Thank you very much!!